# MySQL Generated Columns with NULL value

Tags: mysql

For example, I have 3 columns, `sidea` ,`sideb` and `sidec`. And what I am doing is:

```
CREATE TABLE triangle (
  sidea DOUBLE,
  sideb DOUBLE,
  sidec DOUBLE AS (sidea - sideb)
);
```

But for `sidea`, some of the cell contains `NULL` value. And the result of the above code is that `NULL-(some number)=(some number)`.

Anyone knows how to make `sidec` become `NULL` if any of the cell in `sidea` or `sideb` contain `NULL`?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rgMHxn7uLyjBv1RFxzrLKb/0).

Comment: Can you do the test from the MySQL command line?.

Comment: Hi wchiquito, i just checked, if i use your code, workbench will show NULL as an image. but in my data, NULL is shown as an editable string. My data type for that column is DECIMAL(12,2). I guess NULL is interpreted as string? It was a csv file with blank cell, and what i did is that I use Excel to fill in the blank cell with 'NULL' then input into the database.

Comment: Changing the data type of the columns to `DECIMAL(12,2)`, I also can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rgMHxn7uLyjBv1RFxzrLKb/1). Try to use the MySQL command line.

Comment: It was a csv file with blank cell, and what i did is that I use Excel to fill in the blank cell with 'NULL' then input into the database. I guess the problem is with the NULL.

Comment: MySQL must be performing an implicit conversion of the string `"NULL"` to zero (0), hence that result.

Comment: Yes you are right. so do you have any idea how to make "NULL" as NULL? Thanks.

Comment: See [13.2.6 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html): `The rules for NULL handling are described later in this section.`.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your `CREATE TABLE` script to something as follows:

On the third column, you might want to do a check as like this `CASE WHEN sidea IS Null OR sideb IS Null THEN Null ELSE (sidea-sideb)`

So finally your CREATE TABLE script changes to:

```
CREATE TABLE triangle (
sidea DOUBLE,
sideb DOUBLE,
sidec DOUBLE AS (CASE WHEN sidea IS Null OR sideb IS Null THEN Null ELSE (sidea-sideb) END)
);
```

The `CASE` statement enables you to assign a value `NULL` if either of the column values (namely `sidea` OR `sideb` are NULL then `sidec` is assigned a value NULL).

Hope this helps!